# Что такое 'Zc:forScope-'?

Tags: c++

При сборке кода получил предупреждение компилятора `Предупреждение    D9035   использование параметра "Zc:forScope-" нежелательно, он будет удален в следующих выпусках` как убрать этот параметр(Zc:forScope-) или починить его как то?

Comment: Отключить этот параметр. В 2022 году он не актуален...

Comment: _Отключить этот параметр. В 2022 году он не актуален..._ а как его отключить?

Comment: А где он у вас прописан? Если компиляция через командную строки, чем-то типа make - поискать в соответствующих файлах, если через проект - в свойствах проекта...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-forscope-force-conformance-in-for-loop-scope?view=msvc-170